# Convert Arraylist to a list of items to share through Whatsapp

Tags: java, android, arraylist

i'm developing an App which has an Arraylist with the name of the product and its quantity. Now i want to make an Intent to share this information like a list through the WhatsApp and e-mail, example:

Product: product1     Quantity: 2

Product: product2     Quantity: 5

Product: product3     Quantity: 1

Product: product4     Quantity: 7

or

Product: product1

Quantity: 2

Product: product2

Quantity: 5

Product: product3

Quantity: 1

Product: product4

Quantity: 7

It must send all the information at once like a list.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 0):

So you want to convert the ArrayList which contains strings as
 " product1 , 5 " 
 "Product2 , 3" ...
To one String to share? If so you can use this code.

```
{
    ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
// Your arraylist that contains all the data
        dataList.add("product1 , 5");
        dataList.add("Product2 , 3");
        StringBuilder fullString = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i=0 ; i < dataList.size(); i++)
        {
            String[] splitedData = dataList.get(i).split(",");
            fullString.append("Product : " + splitedData[0] + "\n" + "Quantity : "+ splitedData[1]+"\n");
        }

    ShareToWhatsapp(fullString.toString());
    }
```

Comment: Understood, but in my case i already have the Arraylist that's been feeded from the firestore. it's a shopping list with the list from the client.